# nodejs how to handle a function's error in trycatch

Tags: node.js

I have a method that I want place inside a try catch. How would I change the syntax so it handles it correctly in a trycatch?

```
try{
    rekognition.detectFaces(params, function(err, data) {

    });
}catch(e){

}
```

Getting the error: `error expected to be handled`

Comment: when using node-style callback pattern (`function(err, data)`) error handling is simply `if(err) { /* handle error, return, etc */ }`

Comment: the only way you're gonna get that error out into a synchronous try/catch is by using `async/await` and wrapping the node-style callback in a Promise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably an asynchronous function call -

```js
rekognition.detectFaces(params, function(err, data) {
  // ...
})
```

You cannot wrap such a call with `try`/`catch`. Instead the convention is to handle errors in the callback -

```js
rekognition.detectFaces(params, function(err, data) {
  // handle errors here...
  if (err) {
    // do something
    console.error(err)
  }
  else {
    // no errors here
    console.log(data)
  }
})
```

A better option is to use `util.promisify` -

```js
const { promisify } =
  require("util")

const detectFaces =
  promisify(rekognition.detectFaces.bind(rekognition))

detectFaces(params)
  .then(result => console.log("got result", result))
  .catch(err => console.error("error encountered", err))
```

Such `promisify` function simply converts a callback-style function to Promise-based async function. It's a generic transformation -

```js
const promisify = func =>
  (...args) =>
    new Promise
      ( (resolve, reject) =>
          func
            ( ...args
            , (err, result) =>
                err
                  ? reject(err)
                  : resolve(result)
            )
      )
```

Using the Promised-based function, `try`/`catch` is possible if we also use `async`/`await` -

```js
const detectFaces =
  promisify(rekognition.detectFaces.bind(rekognition))

async function main () {        // <-- async
  try {                         // <-- try
    const result =
      await detectFaces(params) // <-- await

    console.log(result)
  }
  catch (err) {                 // <-- catch
    console.error(err)
  }
}

main()
```

Comment: it's more idiomatic and better practice to `return` in the `if (err)` case to eliminate need for the `else` and bring the entire rest of the callback up one indentation level

Comment: sure, that's all just trading syntax for different styles and preferences. this post only explains how to solve his problem.

Comment: it does, and I've upvoted; I just believe it is always a good idea to include best practices in answers so that readers who copy/paste the answer are not stuck with less maintainable code

Comment: e.g. with `return console.error(err)` you've eliminated the entire `else { ... }` block, reducing the "pyramid of hell" effect and making the code much cleaner

Comment: Klaycon I edited the answer with my recommendation. Never mind `if`/`else` indenting, callback style makes an even bigger mess. `promisify`-ing any callback style function allows us to keep code flat and leverage `async`/`await` where appropriate